# Inserting dynamic text from related table for Data Driven Pages of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, file-geodatabase, data-driven-pages, arcgis-survey123

I'm trying to insert a dynamic text from a related table in a ArcGIS layout using the Data Driven Pages feature to generate automatic reports based on attribute table from a feature class.

I have a geodatabase with a feature class and a related table downloaded from Survey123 for ArcGIS.

Here's the schema of the geodatabase. The source layer used in DDP is `"_3410__Campanha_de_Comunicacao_para_Fase_de_Estudos"`, and the related table is the `"Stakeholder"` file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that this can be done within ArcMap using Data Driven Pages.

It may be possible to do using Map Series and Table Frames within ArcGIS Pro, but I have not tested that.

I am confident that it can be done using ArcPy with "table-like feature classes" in ArcGIS Pro and ArcMap.

For ArcGIS Pro the necessary coding patterns are taught in an eLearning video course on Udemy called [Challenging times with Python and ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro](https://www.udemy.com/challenging-times-with-python-and-arcpy-for-arcgis-pro/).  It is not free, and it uses ArcGIS Pro rather than ArcMap, but the coding patterns taught use functions with equivalents in ArcPy for ArcMap.

**Disclosure**: I am the author and presenter of the Udemy course mentioned above.